# What Kubernetes uses to calculate the CPU ratio, request or limit?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod

When you specify and Horizontal Pod Autoscaler in Kubernetes for example with `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` of 50, what does Kubernetes use to calculate the CPU ratio, the request or the limit of the container?

So for example, with a `request=250` and `limit=500` and you want to scale up when is half its limit:

- If it used the `request`, I would put the target to 100% at least as it can raise to 200%.
- If it used the `limit`, I would use target = 50% as 100% would mean the limit is reached.

Comment: i think you are confusing request and limit with utilization. Consider targetCPUUtilization is 50 and cpu request is 100m . Now if your pod uses more than 50m cpu then it will be scaled up. Request and current utilisation are different things. For autoscaler to work you must define request resources.

Comment: check this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

Comment: @shubham_asati I know the difference between request and limit, what I didn't know is that `targetCPUUtilization` is in regard to requested CPU instead of the limit. But your comment answers it, it compares to the requested value.

Comment: glad to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

targetCPUUtilizationPercentage of 50 means that if average CPU utilization across all Pods goes up above 50% then HPA would scale up the deployment and if the average CPU utilization across all Pods goes below 50% then HPA would scale down the deployment if the number of replicas are more than 1

I just checked the code and found that targetUtilization percentage calculation uses resource request.
refer below code

```
currentUtilization = int32((metricsTotal * 100) / requestsTotal)
```

here is the link 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/pkg/controller/podautoscaler/metrics/utilization.go#L49

Comment: Ok, then, for the question's example you should use the value 100% for target, shouldn't you?

Comment: Yes. You can use value 100 if all the pods are going to have same resources requests. Recommend you to use 80 to 85% if the resource requests  vary